# How to let build fail when docker image size exceeds certain threshold?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

`docker images` returns:

```
REPOSITORY            TAG            IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
<none>                <none>         fcc125757e66   About an hour ago   270 MB
```

**Attempts**

`docker images | awk '{print $6}'` returns:

```
SIZE
ago
hour
ago
ago
ago
```

**Expected outcome**

`270` so this could be used in an if statement:

```
if [ VAR > 250 ] then
   echo "Image too large"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a wrapper script framed out, and you're just asking how to get the size of an image. Is that correct?

Comment: Unverified: awf -F ´\t' ´{ split(" ",$5,arr); print arr[1]}'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `docker images` is really intended for humans, and it's not very parse-friendly. Instead, most Docker commands support a [`--format` flag using Go templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/formatting/). As you can see in the [`images` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output), you only really care about the `.Size` value, so you really want this:

```
docker images --format "{{.Size}}"
```

This just gives an output like this:

```
90.6 MB
```

If you have multiple images, they will each be on a separate line. I'm going to assume you will only ever have one line, because it vastly simplifies the next steps.

To get rid of the `MB`, we can simply use `sed`:

```
docker images --format "{{.Size}}" | sed "s/MB//g"
# => 90.6
```

But, you probably **don't** want this for your bash script. Most shells don't support floating point comparisons, so inputting 90.6 would just fail. Instead, let's use `bc` to truncate the number first:

```
docker images --format "{{.Size}}" | sed "s/MB/\/1/g" | bc
# => 90
```

Note that I've replaced the `MB` with a division by 1, which [truncates in `bc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558710/bc-truncate-floating-point-number).

You can then pipe it into a shell script. I tested with this script:

```
VAR=$(cat)

if [ $VAR -gt "250" ]
    then
    echo "Image too large"
    exit 1
fi
```

Then run with:

```
docker images --format "{{.Size}}" | sed "s/MB/\/1/g" | bc | ./check_size.sh
# Exits with 0 (for my example)
```